# How to use IMemberValueResolver with constructor argument

Tags: c#, automapper

For instance if I have IMemberValueResolver type:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Total,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver, decimal>(src => src.SubTotal));
cfg.CreateMap<OtherSource, OtherDest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OtherTotal,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver, decimal>(src => src.OtherSubTotal));
});

public class CustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, decimal, decimal> {
    public decimal Resolve(object source, object destination, decimal sourceMember, decimal destinationMember, ResolutionContext context) {
// logic here
    }
}
```

What if my CustomResolver is accepting parameter in constructor like:

```
public class CustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, decimal, decimal> {
    public CustomResolver(string text){
    }
    public decimal Resolve(object source, object destination, decimal sourceMember, decimal destinationMember, ResolutionContext context) {
// logic here
    }
}
```

How do I then create map for custom resolver of type IMemberValueResolver?
We can try and supply instance directly:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Total,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver("Text"))
    );
```

But how in this case do we pass which source parameter do we want to use for mapping in resolver?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how can automapper in this case decide what is source from object if we don't pass specific property?

Comment: I understand that, but how do you know which member of source do you want to map to  dest.Total, because you don't specify anywhere, like in first example src.subTotal?

Comment: There is a difference between IValueResolver and IMemberValueResolver. I want to use IMemberValueResolver so I can reuse that resolver, therefore I can pass property instead of whole object. That's not an issue when I don't have custom constructor as you can see in first example. When I have custom constructor I don't know how to pass property like `opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver, decimal>(src => src.SubTotal));`

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you found any way to do this with DI and not using the resolution context or the profile?

Comment: No I don’t use automapper anymore I fully switched to sql stored procedures and dapper

Answer (score 1):

Prety much this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Total,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new CustomResolver("argument"), src => src.SubTotal));
```

But problem is when you have DI linked in resolver as well...

Answer (score -1):

I suppose we should use ResolutionContext to pass the text rather than the constructor.